# Data plotting to estimate answers

Tags: data, mathematica-online

I have some data such that I am estimating the time taken by system to reach at some  stage. For example. 1 sec to reach at stage 1, 3 seconds to reach at stage 2, 5 seconds to reach at stage 3 and so on. As a next step, I want to use this knowledge to estimate the time to reach at final stage at final time say 1000 seconds.
I want to estimate it by using the information of times for 1, 2 and 3 stage and then want to plot to estimate the time to reach for final stage. How can I do it in Mathematica?

Comment: What you're talking about is trying to fit a function according to partial data. There are many ways to do it, but the most important step is to **assume** something about the structure of the function. Do you have any reason to believe that the function $t(n)$ (where $t$ is the time and $n$ is the stage) is polynomial (i.e. linear/quadratic...)? or exponential? or logarithmic? or what?

Comment: The similar kind of thing came in my mind that t should be function of n. The data which I am collecting is kid of experimental observations, where I estimate time to reach at different stages. Need to closely observe if it is linear, exponential etc. I was thinking if there is a way that instead of specifying the function by myself, if it is possible that Mathematica does not require function type from me, rather simply draw by using data.

Answer (score 1):

I begin with a bit of general advice:

You want to find a function $t(n)$ for which you know that $t(n_1)=t_1$, $t(n_2)=t_2$ (where $n_i$ and $t_i$ are your measured data). The problem is that there are **infinitely many** such functions. In order to choose from them the ones that "make sense" you need to apply your *judgement*.

Generally speaking, asking computers for their *judgement* is a bad idea. That is because while computers my be very good at computing, they are (at least as of 2015) very bad at thinking. Say there were a Mathematica function that "guesses" in some way the underlying function - what it actually does is that it uses the programmer's judgement instead of yours. Since there's no way to give a definitive answer to your question ("what is the function?") without applying somebody's judgement, I see no reason to prefer Wolfram's judgement over yours. There's no reason to assume that the programmer is any smarter than you, especially since he didn't see your data.

So my advice is:

1. Plot your data. Look at it. Mash and squish it until it makes sense. Try both linear and logarithmic axes (on both the horizontal and vertical axes) and see whether it looks like something.
2. That said, if all else fails, Mathematica does have a function that tries to guess the underlying function. It's called [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html), but as explained above, I would use it only as a guide, or a starting point.